# Django - page not found 404

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a site using `Django`. I have the index view working, however I want to create a simple custom view and map to it but I am unable to. I'm getting  a `404` error.

The app inside my project is called emails.

Here are the files:

base/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^emails/$', include('emails.urls')),
)
```

emails/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from emails import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^custom/$', views.custom, name='custom'),
)
```

emails/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world, you're at the index.")

def custom(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is a custom view.")
```

Here is the `404`:

Using the `URLconf` defined in `crm.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^admin/
^/emails/$
```

The current URL, emails/custom, didn't match any of these.

When I visit `localhost:8000/emails/` - I see the index view. However `localhost:8000/emails/custom/` is returning a 4`04` error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This `url(r'^emails/$', include('emails.urls')),` should be without the dollar sign `$`:

`url(r'^emails/', include('emails.urls')),`

You don't want to end your path after `emails`, so don't end the string with the regex character `$`. Let it be able to be continued in the other `urls.py` file